# Do you need a multiple Else statements if you run multiple one line If statements?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, if-statement

I have a statement that does two If checks on one line:

```
If JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 Then If JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0 Then meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First Else meaning = ""
```

I'm wondering if I need to add a second Else, as in below:

```
If JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 Then If JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0 Then meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First Else meaning = "" Else meaning = ""
```

Or will the first Else cover all code paths?

Basically, should I be doing

```
If [First Condition] Then If [Second Condition] Then [Result] Else [Nothing happens]
```

Or

```
If [First Condition] Then If [Second Condition] Then [Result] Else [Nothing happens] Else [Nothing happens]
```

I'm aware I could use `AndAlso` as a neater solution, I'm just curious how this one-line nested If would work in practice.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend not using one-line `If` statements for anything but the simplest situations. I never use them. The fact that it's not immediately obvious what's going on here is a reason not to use one in this scenario. If you use a multi-line `If` statement then it is always clear what's happening. That the answer below shows the multi-line equivalent of your code to make it clear what's actually happening should tell you that you should be using a multi-line `If` statement in the first place. Clear code trumps saving a line.

Comment: @jmcilhinney agreed. Outside if something like `If x Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`, one-liners are harder to read and maintain.

Comment: The question is whether the `Else` in `If A Then If B Then C Else D` belongs to the first or second `If`. It belongs to the second and there's no way of knowing that (at least for me) other than testing it (which I did). It's confusing because it's not commonly seen. We have shown clearer ways to write it, which OP probably also could have figured out once the behavior was known. And any question which makes us question our own knowledge is good, so thanks for asking.

Comment: @djv Thanks for the validating the question :). And thanks for testing it! I knew there was an easier and neater way to do what I wanted to, I was mainly curious about what would happen if I did my original solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```vb
If JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 Then If JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0 Then meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First() Else meaning = ""
```

is short for this

```vb
If JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 Then 
    If JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0 Then 
        meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First() 
    Else 
        meaning = ""
    End If
End If
```

So if `JMdict(i).Senses.Count <= 0` then meaning will not be set.

I might do this, using the short circuiting [AndAlso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator) as you mentioned

```vb
If JMdict(i).Senses.Any() AndAlso JMdict(i).Senses.First().Gloss.Any() Then meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First().Gloss.First() Else meaning = ""
```

or use `If()` which shortens the code a little

```vb
meaning = If(JMdict(i).Senses.Any() AndAlso JMdict(i).Senses.First().Gloss.Any(), JMdict(i).Senses.First().Gloss.First(), "")
```

Using `If()` makes it very clear that meaning will be set because we begin with `meaning =`

For the reading impaired, the `If()` function can be split into multiple lines

```vb
meaning = If(JMdict(i).Senses.Any() AndAlso JMdict(i).Senses.First().Gloss.Any(),
             JMdict(i).Senses.First().Gloss.First(), 
             "")
```

You can also use `If()` as a Null Coalescing operator. Note this version of `If()` only takes two arguments

```vb
meaning = If(JMdict(i).Senses.FirstOrDefault()?.Gloss.FirstOrDefault(), "")
```

Comment: The other option is setting `meaning` at the beginning, and then over-writing it if you match the conditions.

Comment: @ts agree to disagree about one liners

Comment: @T.S. I'm with djv here. You know what's unreadable? Something that's gone below the bottom of the screen because it was too long. You can't read what you can't see. You could certainly do the same kind of thing with the linq operations going off to the right (I address this briefly in the middle of my answer), but overall they are tools available to help you get down to just the code that makes sense.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn In my comment I specifically said "such 1-liners". I am not against one liners. But short ones. Even properties `{get {return x;} set {x= value;}}` seem ok. But nested "if" - I wouldn't like that. In fact, I've created coding standards in my company that forbids lines longer than 170 characters and nested single-line conditions. `if something then dothis()` is OK. We also recommend to reduce nesting  where possible. Instead of `if something then do1()  do2()  do3() end if`, use `if not something then return`

Answer (score 1):

The `Else` block on that single line will **NOT** run in all cases. It helps to understand why if you expect that code across multiple lines:

```
If JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 Then 
    If JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0 Then 
        meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First 
    Else 
        meaning = ""
    End If
    'There's no Else block for this spot!
End If
```

To fix this, you have a few options. We could have two `Else` blocks (not a fan of this):

```
If JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 Then 
    If JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0 Then 
        meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First 
    Else 
        meaning = ""
    End If
Else
    meaning = ""
End If
```

Or we can use `AndAlso`:

```
If JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 AndAlso JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0 Then 
    meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First 
Else 
    meaning = ""
End If
```

This is actually pretty good. It's readable, and not too long. But in keeping with the original code in the question, let's stuff it all back on the same line:

```
If JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 AndAlso JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0 Then meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First Else meaning = ""
```

IMO, the above puts a bit too much into a single expression, where you must scroll or mess with line breaks to understand it. Let's work on shortening it more into something we can actually read and parse as a human. I'll start with the `If()` conditional operator:

```
meaning = If(JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 AndAlso JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0, JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First, "")
```

That's a little better, but only a little (128 characters vs 145). We can move some of it to an additional line to set the meaning up front, and then overwrite it only if the condition matches:

```
meaning = ""
If JMdict(i).Senses.Count > 0 AndAlso JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.Count > 0 Then meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.First.Gloss.First
```

Hmmm. Not much improvement. This would have worked better in C#. It's a step, though. From here we can also use slightly different Linq operators plus null conditionals to further simplify things:

```
meaning = JMdict(i).Senses.FirstOrDefault()?.Gloss?.FirstOrDefault()
If meaning Is Nothing Then meaning = ""
```

At last, we're starting to get something that's a reasonable amount of code for a human to process and understand. Plus, we can reduce it even more using the [null-coalescing `If()` variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator#if-operator-called-with-two-arguments):

```
meaning = If(JMdict(i).Senses.FirstOrDefault()?.Gloss?.FirstOrDefault(), "")
```

Now this I like. One line, no scrolling. There are some advanced features that not every VB.Net programmer might know, but even if you've not seem them before you should still be able to follow what the code does.

Comment: @djv Ah, I always forget about that one :(